# how to get video image while posting url in facebook

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, youtube-api

I have an MVC 4.0 application. In one of the views, there is a youtube video. When I copy that URL and try to post that URL in facebook, in facebook it's not showing the image/thumbnail of the video in my MVC app.

For you to understand the problem, try to copy a video URL from youtube and post that copied URL in facebook. Immediately, facebook displays an image/thumbnail of that video in the post. I want to implement that functionality in my ASP.NET MVC application.

Please, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set meta tags for open graph

```
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/t4OEsI0Sc_s/maxresdefault.jpg?feature=og">
 <meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/awesome.flv" />
 <meta property="og:video:height" content="640" />
 <meta property="og:video:width" content="385" />
 <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

Comment: can you explain me code elaberately, do i need to type my web site url instead of example.com?

Comment: Put the `<meta>` tags in your `<head>` section. When you paste a link to facebook, it checks for opengraph meta tags.